Is magnetism an emergent property? Or we just need to just accept it as it is ...as a force that pops out due to the movement of the charge?
Updated and Unupdated Electric Field Vectors: When a charged particle moves, it disrupts the equilibrium of the electric field in its vicinity. This disruption propagates at the speed of light, causing nearby electric field vectors to adjust. However, due to the finite speed of information propagation, there's initially a misalignment between the updated electric field vectors near the particle's new position and the unchanged (unupdated) electric field vectors further away. This misalignment needs to be corrected to maintain continuity in the electric field.
Continuity and Energy Conservation: To maintain continuity in the electric field, the unupdated electric field vectors "stretch" or "elongate" towards the updated ones. However, if this were the only mechanism at play, it would seemingly create energy out of nowhere, thus violating energy
conservation principles. This discrepancy needs to be addressed.
Role of Magnetic Fields: To conserve energy while allowing for smooth adjustments in the electric field, the excess energy from the rearrangement of electric field vectors is temporarily stored elsewhere. This storage occurs in the form of perpendicular magnetic fields. These magnetic fields emerge perpendicular to the plane of the changes in the electric field. By storing the excess energy temporarily, they ensure that energy conservation is maintained.
Perpendicularity of Magnetic Fields: The perpendicularity of the magnetic fields ensures that they don't interfere with the realignment of electric field vectors in the plane. Instead, they serve as a mechanism for temporarily storing and then releasing excess energy, maintaining energy conservation in the system.

This looks more like a personal theory than a question, and also one that is rather different from the well-tested standard theory of electromagnetism (where magnetic fields are the "other side of the coin" to electric fields). It is not clear what to do with it: this site is more for questions that have clear answers.

i gave what i know so that it can be fixed and corrected so am not giving a personal theory but rather asking for a fact check to my understanding...sorry if i made it look that way

Yes, but this site is not great for fact checking in this way.

This (v3) is copied directly from ChatGPT. It can't be more obvious. Such content should be flagged as abusive.

the idea is totally mine only thing i said to chat is to orgnize it and not change anything so yeh its still mine and there is no issue in reorgnizing my thoughts. i mean its good i guess that u thought it was chat who wrote this by itself so maybe my idea is accurate

Short answer – No. Every electron and proton (and even neutron, slightly) is by itself a tiny dipole magnet. Even in its own rest frame. It's called intrinsic magnetic moment.
So some magnetic fields exist apart from moving charges.

Who knows? may be the electron is rotating. There are no spin zero particles with magnetic moment, and I believe no fundamental neutral particle with magnetic moment either (but I am not sure about this one)

electron dont rotate but still also just assaining magnetic force to spin is still dont awnser how magnetisme comes for tahat i think my same explenation uplies just at a way smaller scale ...spin distorts the electric field very close to particule so there will be some updated and unupdated vector...so inorder for them to connect some energy will be preserved in z direction giving rize to magnetisme...but magnetic force is weaker way weaker compared to a mooving charge because spin distored the electric field in a way smaller manner so the corrections needing magentisme are way less
